# How to prevent a TTree being written to a TFile

Tags: c++, root-framework

In my ROOT script, I have a `TTree` which I create but never wish to save. What is the best way to ensure the `TTree` never gets saved to a `TFile`?

I have thought of creating a `TFile` for every tree I create but doesn't need saving, but it feels like there should be an easier way to mark the `TTree` as not to be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `TTree::SetDirectory`. Pass in a 0 pointer and there will be no "owner" directory, including no ROOT memory management.

Comment: This is possibly what I'm after, although this causes the `TTree` to disappear when I try to access it.

Comment: It's rather long and difficult to untangle, I'll try and make a MWE if I can't trace the error.

Comment: Using `tree->SetDirectory(0)` works properly, but also affects the connected tree (as I created `tree` with `TTree::CopyTree`) which is a separate problem.

Comment: Yes, the ROOT memory structure is a bit off-putting. You might want to have a lot at TROOT (aka global var gROOT: https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTROOT.html) where you can switch the memory context between files, directories and a temporary dir (RAM?). At least when it comes to histograms `SetDirectory` can be set globally. Maybe that's what happened with your TTree (hard to say without looking at the TTree code)